# site under maintainence for php and IIS server

Tags: php, iis

I have a website running on php symfony2 framework with IIS has the web server .I wanted to display Site Under maintainence message whenever there is prod deployment .I tried using app_offline.htm by placing in the root driectory of my website  but didn't workout. 
Can someone suggest me a better way of handling this or how to make this work.
Any suggestion would be appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Why ever put it in maintenance? That's what Doctrine Migrations are for!

Comment: is there a way to handle by IIS

Comment: Yes, IIS should be able to handle `php app/console` commands just like any other web server.